# Ansible Playbook Directory Structure - using /files at playbook_dir level

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

### QUESTION; TLDR

Are there suggestions on handling **FILES** and **VAULT FILES** within a playbook and not within **ROLES**?

### EXPLANATION

I'm familiar with the following [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) from ansible where the following directory structure is listed as such:

```
inventories/
   production/
      hosts               # inventory file for production servers
      group_vars/
         group1.yml       # here we assign variables to particular groups
         group2.yml
      host_vars/
         hostname1.yml    # here we assign variables to particular systems
         hostname2.yml

   staging/
      hosts               # inventory file for staging environment
      group_vars/
         group1.yml       # here we assign variables to particular groups
         group2.yml
      host_vars/
         stagehost1.yml   # here we assign variables to particular systems
         stagehost2.yml

library/
module_utils/
filter_plugins/

site.yml
webservers.yml
dbservers.yml

roles/
    common/
    webtier/
    monitoring/
    fooapp/
```

This structure works for simple projects. However a very large playbook, that uses `requirements.yml` to git clone roles into it's structure makes it hard to maintain items like vault files because of possible drift in vault-passwords amongst the myriad repos. From my perspective, it would be useful if the vaulted files were in a central location at the playbook level.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a `playbook_dir/vault | files` directory, at the same level as `inventories` or perhaps a `playbook_dir/inventories/group_vars/vault | files` directory. Then within this `vault | files` folder I can centralize all my necessary secret/non-secret files (such as certs and other items too long winded to be stored as a variable).

That way when the playbook is ran for `[servers]` it will get all the necessary variables AND `vaulted | files` that I need the host group to share.

Comment: There are also some default [search paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html) for playbook, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Yes, I have explored that option. I create a playbook_dir/vault folder, then in inventories/group_vars I create a variable: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../files/cacerts.pem" but boy does that get soupy quick when I have 100+.

Though that is the ONLY true option I've found yet

Comment: There is an option of linking files and directories. Put all secrets into a central vault, for example in the root directory of your projects. Then link whatever is needed into the *group_vars*, *host_vars*, role *vars* ...

Comment: I don't understand your question. `files` subdir at playbook level is searched in the exact same way as in `roles/<some_role>/files`. Moreover I don't get why on earth you would put any vault encrypted file/secret/var inside a role (which should be reusable by anyone by definition...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to work with the advised by seshadri_c and Vladimir Botka. The search paths appear to be the best solution for the vault files and regular files.

1. Place a `files` folder at the root of playbook
2. Place a valuted file in the base files folder
3. Within the role, refer to a general variable `'{{ vaulted-file }}'`
4. Hopefully, the search paths will resolve without having to do relative pathing (such as `../../files/{{ vaulted-file }}` )

Thank you.